# Qual a diferença entre variáveis de instância de classe, automáticas (locais) e de duração estática?

Tags: c#, classes, variáveis

Qual a diferença entre esses tipos variáveis? Como identificá-las? Como o C# trabalha com elas?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 6):

[O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)

> variável de instância

Esta variável pertence ao objeto, concretamente ela só existe quando objeto é criado. Na classe ela serve apenas de planta de como criar o objeto. Em todos os métodos de instância você pode acessá-la porque internamente tem um parâmetro (`this`) em todos os métodos de instância já que eles recebem o objeto (geralmente por referência) sem você ver.

Elas só podem ser acessadas através de um objeto. Não pode ser acessada pela classe ou outra forma, tem que dizer de qual objeto você quer a variável.

```
class Exemplo {
    private int valor;
    public string nome;
}
```

> variável de classe

São variáveis que existem por todo o tempo de vida da aplicação, elas são acessadas através da classe porque só existe uma dela, não é como os objetos que podem ter vários. Então podemos entender que há um objeto único na memória com as variáveis da classe. Estas variáveis são compartilhadas por toda a aplicação (a não ser que sejam privadas).

```
class Exemplo {
    public static int total;
}
```

> variável automática (variável local)

São as variáveis dos métodos, geralmente presentes no *stack* (pode estar no registrador). Eles tem seu tempo de vida gerenciado automaticamente enquanto o método estiver executando. São chamadas de automáticas por isso.

```
class Exemplo {
    public static int total;
    private int valor;
    public string nome;
    public string Metodo(int parametro) => (total + valor + parametro).ToString() + nome;
}
```

Note que parâmetros são variáveis locais, a diferença é só a inicialização que é feita na chamada do método.

> variável de duração estática

O mesmo que variável de classe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/VariableEscopeTypes.cs)