# Qual seria diferença entre campos e variáveis no C#?

Tags: .net, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, campos

Qual seria diferença entre campos e variáveis no C#?

Comment: Campo é uma variável de qualquer tipo.

Comment: [Campos (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173118(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Campo normalmente é o nome utilizado para variáveis privadas de escopo de classe e variável é normalmente utilizado para se referir a variáveis de escopo local dentro de um método por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já lhe mostrei antes o que é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

O campo é um membro de uma estrutura de dados, ou seja, de um tipo como `struct` ou `class` que contém um estado, ou seja, um valor. Este valor pode ser constante ou variável. Portanto campo é um jeito específico de ter uma variável.

Então o campo estará presente em tipos, no caso os campos estáticos, ou estará em instâncias (que você [já perguntou o que é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/338603/101)).

Não faz diferença se a visibilidade do campo é privada, protegida, interna ou pública.

Se quiser saber sobre a diferença entre a variável local e a variável de instância (pela pergunta não é isso, mas em todo caso...), já [foi respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257817/101).

[Algumas pessoas confundem atributo com campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). As linguagens de programação possuem campo e não atributo, pelo menos neste contexto. Atributo é outra para as linguagens. Infelizmente UML usa esse termo para campo, e as pessoas entendem errado e aí misturam conceitos em contextos diferentes, escrevem artigos, respostas e até livros de forma errada.

Por outro lado talvez queria saber sobre a [Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101).

Também deve ser do interesse: [Qual a diferença em instanciar, inicializar e declarar uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/101). Também pode querer saber [Campo público X propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101). E ainda [Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101). Como já falei antes se pesquisar no site e seguir *links* vai encontrar vários conteúdos muito bons para aprender estes conceitos.